# How do I sign a powershell script with in-network server so that all clients can run script without changing execution policy?

Tags: powershell, certificate

I am trying to deploy a fix in a closed enterprise environment. I want to create script that will fix an issue I have but need it to be able to run without changing execution policy. This network is in-house and does not connect out to be able to purchase a trusted certificate so I'm hoping to have one of our servers sign? All user and workstation authentication runs through one local certificate authority but don't know if I can create a cert from it that windows will allow through execution policy.

I have been working with trying to bypass execution policy but haven't managed to find a way to do it automatically and safely on our older version of powershell.

Comment: An ADCS CA? ADCS comes with a built-in template called "Code Signing" that you can use to issue a new signing certificate (which you can then use to sign the scripts)

Comment: This is not a certificate issue.  It is a credential issue.  All server use a common Password Server.  Is your company using Group Policy?  Is there a group for all the clients that you can use?  To run a script on a remote machine you have to have an account that is recognized on all servers.   If you are running As Admin don't forget to change any paths like 'c:\' to 'c$\'.  The dollar sign is what is used for ADMIN.

Comment: I will have to look into these. We only sort of use active directory.  As in, it's used for users and computers authentication but not GPOs. My admin account is recognized on all systems, but I still can't push script to any machines with a configured execution policy as my code isn't "signed"

Comment: If you're getting an error that your code script/code isn't signed. Could you please provide the error in your question? The more details we have have the easier it is for us to help you.

Comment: It's the standard *.ps1 cannot be loaded because execution of scripts is disabled on this machine, please see "get- help about_signing" for details.